# Basic authentication with HTTPRIO in Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi, authentication, delphi-10.3-rio

There has been a change to  the `HTTPRIO.HTTPWebNode.OnBeforePost` event in Delphi 10.3.

Before Delphi 10.3, the event handler was defined this way, and it worked perfectly:

```
procedure TForm1.HTTPRIO1HTTPWebNode1BeforePost(const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp;
  Data: Pointer);
var
  auth: String;
begin
  auth := 'Authorization: Basic ' + IdEncoderMIME1.EncodeString('user:password');
  HttpAddRequestHeaders(Data, PChar(auth), Length(auth), HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD);
end;
```

In Delphi 10.3, the `Data` parameter is gone, instead a `THTTPClient` is given, and I have no idea how to implement Basic authentication with it:

```
procedure TForm1.HTTPRIO1HTTPWebNode1BeforePost(const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp;
  Client: THTTPClient);
var
  auth: String;
begin
  auth := 'Authorization: Basic ' + IdEncoderMIME1.EncodeString('user:password');
  ???
end;
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the request's [`Username`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Soap.SOAPHTTPTrans.THTTPReqResp.UserName) and [`Password`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Soap.SOAPHTTPTrans.THTTPReqResp.Password) properties, eg:

```
HTTPReqResp.UserName := 'user';
HTTPReqResp.Password := 'password';
```

If that does not work, try using the client's [`CustomHeaders`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Net.URLClient.TURLClient.CustomHeaders) property instead, eg:

```
Client.CustomHeaders['Authorization'] := 'Basic ' + IdEncoderMIME1.EncodeString('user:password');
```

Comment: 2nd proposition works! 1st unfortunatelly not. Thanks!

Comment: dont forget to enable basic auth

Comment: @AdriaanBoshoff hi, I have the same problem. The secons solution works, but the 1st one seems more elegant. You've mentioned enabling basic auth. Where can I enable this? I've explored components (TNetHTTPClient  and TNetHTTPRequest), but haven't found an option. From serverside it's probably enabled, because I can use other REST client to access it via basic auth.

Comment: Look at the properties. There's one called `BasicAuthentication`. Set that to true.

Answer (score 1):

Using THttpClient the below worked for me in 10.3.2 (I couldn't find the lib for IdEncoderMIME1). I was able to post to an api using basic authentication.

HTTP.CustomHeaders['Authorization'] := 'Basic ' + TNetencoding.Base64.Encode('user:pass');

Comment: "*I couldn't find the lib for IdEncoderMIME1*" - the `TIdEncoderMIME` class is part of Indy, which comes pre-installed with the IDE.