# Basic Authentication Header Parsing at Delphi Soap Server

Tags: delphi, soap, basic-authentication

I created simple soap server application. I send basic auth header values, like this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54833530/basic-authentication-with-httprio-in-delphi-10-3).

I can see auth header values.

[image]

Is there any way to parse header values at soap server application ?

Thanks.

Comment: The AUTH header is a HTTP header common to all web requests not just SOAP calls. How to access the headers depends on what components you are using to handle web requests.

Comment: As per [RFC 2617](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2617) it's one of HTTP header lines. If you'd have read the very first line you'd have noticed `HTTP/1.1` already, which is unrelated to SOAP.

Comment: Other technologies providing access http request headers, such as c#. I want simply http headers in soap application.That's it.

Comment: Would it be OK for you to access the authorization information in `TWebModule` or do you need it in your implementation of `TInvokableClass` descendant?