# Delphi 10.4 SOAP basic authentication missing header

Tags: delphi, soap, basic-authentication

I'm using

HTTPRio1.HTTPWebNode.UserName := 'XXXXXXXX';
HTTPRio1.HTTPWebNode.Password := 'XXXXXXXX';

There is no header in the XML submission
But I always get the same answer "An error was discovered processing the wsse:Security header."
Does anyone have any idea what is wrong or what is missing for this to work!

Comment: Maybe this question has the answer you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54833530/basic-authentication-with-httprio-in-delphi-10-3

Comment: I have already tried this and it does not work either, there is never any hedder in xml from Delphi

Comment: IMO the authentication is not in the XML but in the HTTP header.

Comment: It looks like the server expects [WS-Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security).

Comment: yes you need wsse.pas. Use the one from [this post](https://forum.delphi.cz/index.php/topic,15329.0.html) (it's in czech language, use google translate).