# How to add custom HTTP headers in a SOAP request using C++Builder

Tags: c++, soap, http-headers, c++builder-xe2

I am trying to add custom HTTP headers in a SOAP request using C++Builder XE2. As I didn't see any c++ template, I used as sample [the following Delphi code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54833530/basic-authentication-with-httprio-in-delphi-10-3) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360581/soap-message-add-authentication-in-http-header), but without any success.
The event handler is even not triggered.

Any idea to fixe the issue will be really appreciated.

Below is my code.

```
//.h
private:    // Déclarations utilisateur
    void __fastcall HTTPRIOBeforePost(const THTTPReqResp* HTTPReqResp, void * Data);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//.cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{//
 _di_MyServicesPort MSPort = NS_MyServices::GetMyServicesPort(true, "https://www.example.com/MyServices.wsdl");

 // /Set headers
 THTTPRIO *HTTPRIO = new THTTPRIO(NULL);
 HTTPRIO->URL = L"https://www.example.com/MyServices.wsdl";
 HTTPRIO->HTTPWebNode->OnBeforePost = &HTTPRIOBeforePost;
 // \Set header

 UnicodeString US_MSPort = MSPort->TESTDisplay(-1);
//...
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::HTTPRIOBeforePost(const THTTPReqResp* HTTPReqResp, void * Data)
{//
 HttpAddRequestHeaders(Data, TEXT("UserID: My_UserID\r\n"), -1, HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD | HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_REPLACE);
 HttpAddRequestHeaders(Data, TEXT("Password: My_Password\r\n"), -1, HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD | HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_REPLACE);
 HttpAddRequestHeaders(Data, TEXT("Content-Type: My_Content-Type\r\n"), -1, HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD | HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_REPLACE);
 HttpAddRequestHeaders(Data, TEXT("User-Agent: My_User-Agent\r\n"), -1, HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD | HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_REPLACE);
 HttpAddRequestHeaders(Data, TEXT("Authorization: My_Authorization\r\n"), -1, HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD | HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_REPLACE);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
``
```